# How can I test my Google Analytics integration?

Tags: google-analytics, turbolinks, capybara-webkit

I have a customized GA integration in order to work more smoothly with turbolinks. (Based loosely on: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html)

Now like a good little code monkey I want to cover my code in my tests. After much googling I found a surprising dearth of acceptable testing methods. Mostly just a manual make sure the code/tracking pixel is present sort of thing. Which obviously won't work long term; someone will forget to check a page or an interaction type and broken code will ship.

So how can I automatically test that my integration of GA is working correctly? (I'm already using capybara-webkit for integration testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of the GA js that logs all activity to the browser console ([ga_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting?csw=1#gaDebug)). Capybara-webkit allows you to access the browser console log from the driver which means that you can simply wrap your actions in `assert_difference('page.driver.console_messages.select {|m| m[:message] == "Track Pageview" }.length',n) do ... end` and get really slick testability of your code.

There's also a version for universal analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug you just have to adjust your message filter to catch the right messages.

While there are other approaches, such as mocking out GA or setting up a proxy server; they are more work and require me to know what the GA server expects from the GA client code, and update when that changes. This way I don't have to change a thing, just use the correct client library for the job.